# iOSの AssetsCatalog の Slicing において素材の四隅を伸ばす方法がわからない

Tags: ios

Assets Catalog の真ん中の要素を固定（中央合わせ、引き伸ばしなし）して画面の幅に応じて適当な色をリピートさせたいと考えておりますが、四隅を伸ばす方法がわからずに困っています。

用途はプレースホルダー画像を動的に生成させるためです。

※例えば下記のWebサイトの数字のサイズ固定でグレーを伸ばしたい
http://via.placeholder.com/350x150

調べていく中で Assets Catalog のSlicingを使用して四隅を伸ばすことができないと思ったのですが、どのように実現させるのがベストか教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

Slicingは縁を固定して中央を引き伸ばす機能なので、希望の動作をさせることはできないと思います。

代わりの方法としては

1. 背景透過の画像をサイズ固定 ( Content Mode = Center ) で中央に配置し、UIImageViewか別のビューで背景色をつける
2. UIImageView の上に 表示したい文字を設定した UILabel を置いて、AutoLayoutなどで位置を中央、サイズを固定にする。UIImageViewには適当な背景画像か背景色を設定する
3. CGGraphicContextなどを使って、動的に画像を生成する

辺りではないかと思います。
中央に表示したいのが文字列ならば 2. が楽じゃないかと思います。